# Caliburn Micro simple MDI

Tags: wpf, mdi, caliburn.micro

Hi I create simpel MDI in caliburn micro something like this :  http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/10/19/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-6c-simple-mdi-with-screen-collections.aspx.

Every tab item is identified by ID (ID is DisplayName propety). I need have opened only single tab item for every id.Tab item is user control.

Tab item view model class is here:

```
[Export(typeof(ITabChatViewModel))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class TabChatViewModel : Screen, IViewModelIdentity,
    IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification,
    ITabChatViewModel, IHandle<IRp>, IHandle<IDetailData>
{...}
```

So if I activate tab item in shell I store tab ID in list.

I need something remove tab ID from list when is tab item deactivate.

Shell view model class:

```
[Export(typeof(IChatShellViewModel))]
public class ChatShellViewModel : 
    Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, 
    IChatShellViewModel
{
    //consist active tab item
    List<string> ActiveTabItems { get; set; }

    public ChatShellViewModel()
    {
        ActiveTabItems=new List<string>();
    }

    public void OpenChatTab(IScreen screen)
    {
        if(!ActiveTabItems.Contains(screen.DisplayName))
        {
            ActivateItem(screen);
           ActiveTabItems.Add(screen.DisplayName);
        }

    }


}
```

Shell view:

```
<Window x:Class="Spirit.Views.ChatShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro" 
        Height="545" 
        Width="680">
    <DockPanel>
        <TabControl x:Name="Items">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"  
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Image Source="/images/icons/close.png" 
                                       Margin="8,4,4,4" 
                                       Height="16" 
                                       Width="16"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseLeftButtonDown]=[Action CloseItem($dataContext)]"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I can achieve this behavior with event aggregator class and publish message from tab item view model class on shell view model class
when is tab item deactivated.

But I would like use something more simple. For example tab item can call shell view method when is deactivated.

Any advice? Thank

Comment: You should use button instead of image+mousedown (and then style it flat) because it handles touch, stylus and mouse interaction with the "Click" event - it also handles the scenario where mousedown happens on the button but mouseup doesnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Screen` class (which is provided by the framework) that you are inheriting `TabChatViewModel` from, defines the method `TryClose`. This method attempts to close the current screen by either asking its Parent (which in your case will be the `ChatShellViewModel` conductor) or asking the view to close.

So all you need to do is call `TryClose()` from within the `TabChatViewModel` when the close operation is invoked.